# TkHTML Example Not Working - Possible Problems with ASCII Encoding or Urllib?

Tags: html, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am using the wrapper TkHTML with Python 2.7 on a Windows 10 machine.  I am trying to run the basic program example that comes with the download at [https://bitbucket.org/aivarannamaa/tkinterhtml/src/master/tkinterhtml/**main**.py?fileviewer=file-view-default](https://bitbucket.org/aivarannamaa/tkinterhtml/src/master/tkinterhtml/__main__.py?fileviewer=file-view-default) (by the stack overflow user Aivar), but it isn't working.

Here is the code:

```
import urllib.request
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

from tkinterhtml import HtmlFrame

root = tk.Tk()

frame = HtmlFrame(root, horizontal_scrollbar="auto")
frame.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)


frame.set_content("""
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<p>First para</p>
<ul>
    <li>first list item</li>
    <li>second list item</li>
</ul>
<img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/638/magic_people/128/magic_ball.png"/>
</body>
</html>    
""")

frame.set_content(urllib.request.urlopen("http://thonny.cs.ut.ee").read().decode())
#print(frame.html.cget("zoom"))


root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.mainloop()
```

It gives the error:

```
File "C:/Users/Chris/Anaconda2/Lib/site-packages/tkinterhtml/__main__.py", line 30, in <module>
    frame.set_content(urllib.request.urlopen("http://tkhtml.tcl.tk/").read().decode())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
```

I read somewhere that urllib.request is only in Python 3, but urllib2 is the older version still in 2.7. So, I tried replacing the import urllib with import urllib2 and then changing urllib.request.urlopen to urllib2.urlopen. No dice.

Finally, I tried the following

```
    opened_file=urllib2.urlopen("http://thonny.cs.ut.ee")
    opened_file.read().decode('utf-8')
    frame.set_content(opened_file)
```

and got the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2680: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm going crazy here. All I want is to display html code in a TKinter window. It doesn't seem like it should be too hard, but it just isn't happening for me. Any help would be great.

Comment: always put in question FULL error message (Traceback), not only last part. There are other usefull information.

Comment: maybe install Python 3 instead of 2 - (or [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) with Python 3)

Comment: this code works for me on Linux. I had to change only `urllib.request.urlopen()` into `urllib.urlopen()`. With `urllib2` works too.

Comment: BTW: you have to assign decoded text `opened_file = opened_file.read().decode('utf-8')` and maybe it is your problem.

Comment: Thank you for responding - I apologize for not including the whole error messages. I am using some python code in conjunction with other programs that require Python 2. I added the opened_file = opened_file.read().decode('utf-8') you suggested, but it hasn't helped, unfortunately. I get the following:   C:\Users\Chris\Anaconda2\python.exe C:/Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/TestTKHTML/Test.py

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: I don't use WIndows so I can help with "exit code". As for "UnicodeDecodeError" - it is very popular error in Windows but only when you use `print()` because cmd.exe/console in Windows doesn't use `UTF-8` and it has problem to display it - but I don't see `print()` in your code.